# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS support for Dell U3415W monitor

Tags: drivers, usb, keyboard, mouse

I'm using a Dell U3415W monitor which has a keyboard-video-mouse switch built in. I'm trying to share the monitor, mouse and keyboard between a Windows 7 desktop and and Intel NUC running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I'm using a wireless Logitech M510 mouse and a Microsoft Wireless Comfort 5000 wireless keyboard. The mouse and keyboard use USB dongles to connect wirelessly.

The monitor requires the dongles be plugged into USB ports on the monitor. Then, the two PCs are connected to the monitor via two USB 2.0 hub connections (the hub end of the USB cords plug into monitor, the standard connection on the other end of the cord plugs into either a USB 2.0 or 3.0 port on the PCs).

The problem is getting the Ubuntu machine to see the keyboard and mouse after switching to it. The monitor looks fine and displays the image, but the keyboard and mouse won't work. I assume this is because the Ubuntu machine goes to sleep and then can't see the USB peripherals when it wakes up.

Connecting both the mouse and keyboard dongles directly to the Ubuntu machine works fine, they just don't work when operating through the switch in the monitor.

Anyone have thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue as you. My workaround has been to make sure I switch the display back to my Ubuntu machine before letting the monitor go to sleep. If the monitor goes to sleep while displaying the Windows machine, then all USB peripherals on my Ubuntu machine fail, and a reboot is the only way to fix. So, this seems to be a bug in the USB hub of the U3415W, but it may also be a bug in the Linux kernel itself. I would love to find a better solution!